# Trying to run a Directory.Exists() with a system variable vs drive letter

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to run a C# program to determine if a directory exists on multiple servers, so I need to run it as `%system Variable%`, rather than making a drive letter call, since not every server will have the same drive letter. This is what I have:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("D:\backup") Then
```

This code will work, as I define the drive

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("%BCK_DRV%\backup") Then
```

This will not, I get my else error when running it. The `%BCK_DRV%` is defined in the environment variables, and I can navigate to the folder without issue using  `%BCK_DRV%\backup`. Is there a special way to set and define a `%drive%` in C#?

Comment: I think you are looking for the [System.SpecialFolder Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)  With that in mind, backup drive is not in that enum.  This may help with other system variables though.

Answer (score 2):

[Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Code sample:

```
Dim backupDrive As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BCK_DRV") & "\backup"
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(backupDrive) Then
```

Comment: could you add some content from that link in case the link goes bad, then the answer has more merit when people do searches and find this.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string raw      = @"%BCK_DRV%\backup" ;
string expanded = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables( path_raw ) ;
```

Naturally, it's up to you to ensure that your process inherits the correct environment.

Answer (score 0):

To expand "%BCK_DRV%\backup" to it's real value you need

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables();
```

Example:

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%winDir%\test")
```

will expand to "C:\Windows\test" (on my system).